# Answering own questions, through the outcome of another answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, accepted-answer, duplicate-answers, attribution

I haven't found answer in a pure form on my question, but I'd like to clarify this case for the future use/moderation/"help" section improving.

**Answering own questions, through the outcome of another answer - how to behave?**

Situation is next, with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35846805/4354249). Author of question was not managed to find the solution himself. I given extensive and [explicit **answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35846930/4354249). I made also several improvements of answer, after iterative discussion, and additional questions from the author. With the edits, I made sure it will help other guys, who might hit the same question. And finally my answer helped to solve his task.

Instead of accepting my answer, author re-posted **the same** solution, but [included his specific code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851252/4354249), which is one to one the outcome of our discussion and my answer. Later on he accepted his solution, instead of mine answer, with long discussion which actually helped him.

The manual unambiguously states [acceptance behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer):

> **Accepting an answer** is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that **the author received an answer that worked for him** or her personally...

At the same time the help section says [how to behave with referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). And the author haven't even referenced that the solution he gotten, is an outcome of my help and explicit, qualitative answer.

I need to understand my behavior, in such case, as community member, as moderator, as the contributor. After analysis and review of "help" section, of "meta" community, I came to next possible solutions.

### Behavior cases:

1. **Flag this answer** with an option "*in need of moderator intervention*", for further deletion, and to specify "answer is a duplicate and outcome of the original answer [link]". Plus *post the comment* to the author with the corresponding links from help, mentioned above.
2. If I'm as moderator, seeing this, should be the rule to **delete such answer as a duplicate**?
3. Author of the question, has to mark the question which helped as accepted, but if he wants to post some snippets, he may **post as EDIT: part to the question itself**, with the reference, that is was outcome of answer.
4. To **extend the help section**, and to cover this specific case, for future use, with clear **instructions for moderators** as well.
5. The author **may post answers**, as an outcome of someone's answer on the same question, but *with mandatory reference*.
6. The author **may post answers**, as an outcome of someone's answer on the same question, **no specific rules, it's fine**, and it's not mandatory to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and to reward other contributors.

Looking forward for the chosen case, and some laconic explanations, how to behave in such situations and to be objective. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd go the way "5. The author may **post answers, as an outcome of someone's answer** on the same question, but **with mandatory reference.**". And would like to hear all pros and cons of my decision.

Comment: The two answers are so different so it is difficult to judge how much of the earlier answer was used in the latter (quite different) answer. It's kind of debatable how much the second answer is really an outcome of the first. Attribution is only required when directly taking parts of another answer, a neutral bystander would find it hard to require attribution in this case. From the dates of the answers it's clear that your answer existed first and one should always assume that every later answerer draws from earlier approaches. So you did a good deed, if that makes you happy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question author is entirely within their rights to take the information you used in your answer in order to solve their problem, and then post the solution they eventually arrived at as an answer.

They are also free to accept whatever answer they want.  It is *their* decision what answer was most helpful for them, not anyone else's.

There is no reason to flag this answer.  If it were flagged, it'd just be declined.  There is no reason for this answer to be deleted.

Your suggestion to have the author edit their answer into the question, rather than posting an answer, is the exact *opposite* of what they should be doing.  If they have come up with a solution to their problem we *want* them to post an answer.  If they edit an answer into the question then that is inappropriate, and should be edited *out* of the question if you see someone do it.

If you think that the answer isn't useful, you're free to downvote it, and optionally comment on it to explain why you don't think that the answer is adding any useful content beyond the existing answers to the question.

Comment: But also attribution has to be given though before copying part of an answer into another. In this case the OP did modify the answer so much that it's unclear if he must give attribution but in general it's always nice to reference the sources of your work.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't see anything in that answer that would require attribution.  It doesn't seem to be duplicating pretty much anything from the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'd also like to hear your opinion on rewarding the answer which helped to solve and to move from the dead point and **providing at least reference** on the answer which generated the solution.

Comment: @Farside For all you know they did upvote your answer.  They are of course not obligated to reward your answer in any way.  They certainly aren't obligated to accept your answer, under any circumstances, for any reason.  As I said, I see nothing in their answer that would require attribution to anything in your answer; it seems to contain entirely new information.

Comment: @Servy, sounds like it's not forbidden to take someone's solutions, and simply to extend it, without any reference.

Comment: @Farside I don't see his solution as having taken yours.  It's *dramatically* different.

Comment: I would have to agree Trilarion the above. While it's entirely up to the OP what answer to accept, there should be some level of attribution even if it is simply adding a, "Thanks to Farside for getting me here..." in the accepted answer. The accepted answer contains a lot of new information, but Farside's answer and subsequent follow up is what lead to that new information. Reading passed the answer and into the comments, it is clear that the OP had a lot of help in arriving at their solution and may have been stuck with their problem in perpetuity if someone had not walked them through it.

Comment: @asp8811 What you have described is not actually attribution.  The fact that someone else posted an answer and responded to comments doesn't, in and of itself, make the answer the OP posted plagiarism.

Comment: Servy, I'd rather agree with @asp8811, as I definitely lead him to the solution, it's not something he solved himself. But let's **not** deep into specific my case. I want you to think **in general**, about this situation and rules how to behave.

Comment: @Farside So by that logic you should be citing all of your teachers, from your entire educational history, for helping you get to the point where you were able to learn enough to post the answer that you did, right?  Like I said, there is pretty clearly no plagiarism of any of the content of your answer in the OP's answer.  I see nothing that would necessitate a citation.  You can argue that you helped him all you want, but that doesn't mean that the content of his answer is your content, because it's pretty clearly *not*.

Comment: @Farside As far as the general case, I answered the general case.  If the OP has come up with an answer to their question, they should post it as an answer.  They are free to do so, and if they want to accept it, it's fine.  That is the answer to the general case of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, @Servy for you input, I appreciate your answer. Let's not deep into discussions in comments, you answer was explicit.

Comment: What if the answer posted by the OP is an exact duplicate of your answer? Should you ask them to upvote/accept your answer instead of posting an exact duplicate?

Comment: @cst1992 That would be plagiarism, and you should flag it appropriately for a moderator to deal with.